# Work-Energy Theorem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, potential-energy

Regarding the function theorem: W (non-conservative force) = △ K, this formula I once derived, it is also acceptable, but I saw W = △ K + △ U in the reference book a few days ago, I don't understand this, how can there be △ U? And how to derive it?

Comment: I hesitate to guess at an answer because I don't exactly know what is meant by the terms $W$, $\Delta K$, and $\Delta U$. Give their definitions.

Comment: W(Work), K(Kinetic energy), U(Potential Energy)

Comment: Which reference book? Which page?

Comment: I don't know where you got that $W_{non conservative} = \Delta K$ but According to W.E.P ,  $W_{non conservative} + W_{conservative} + W_{external forces}  = \Delta K $

Comment: And for a body having initial $K.E$ and $P.E$ as $K_i$ and $U_i$ respectively ,  $K_i + U_i + W_{nonconservative} + W_{external} = K_f + U_f $. Depending on scenarios , some of the variables are 0 .

Comment: You might have seen the modified version of the W.E.E that states $W_{non conservative} + W_{external} = \Delta K +\Delta U $. If in the given situation , $\Delta U = 0 $ and $ W_{external}=0 $ , then you get $W_{non conservative}= \Delta K$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an isolated system with conservative forces only, the total change in kinetic plus potential energy is zero, meaning mechanical energy is conserved.

$$\Delta K + \Delta U =0$$

If the system is not isolated so that there is a net external force acting upon the system, then any change in the sum of the kinetic and potential energies of the system will equal the net work $W$ done by that external force on the system, or

$$W=\Delta K + \Delta U$$

Regarding your theorem:

W (non-conservative force) = △ K

There is no potential energy associated with non-conservative forces. Therefore there is no $\Delta U$ associated with the work done by non-conservative forces.

The work done by non-conservative forces can result in either an increase or decrease in kinetic energy. Per the work-energy theorem, the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy.

An example of the work done by a non-conservative force is the work done by dissipative forces, such as kinetic friction forces which cause a reduction in kinetic energy. An example is an object sliding on a surface with friction. The only work done on the object is the negative work of kinetic friction. Kinetic friction brings the object to rest converting the object's kinetic energy to heat.

Hope this helps.